# how to create dynamic a html form with dropdown listbox in php which get data from mysql database?

Tags: php, html

I have created a form in html with dropdown list box with static values inside a php file, now i need to populate those dropdown with data from mysql database. i have written a function in php to retrive data from the mysql table. since i am new to php i don't know how to call a php function from html. is it possible to call a php function like calling a JavaScript function.

Here is my HTMl code.

```
 <div id="machinelog">
    <form id="intermediate" name="inputMachine" method="post">

    <select id="selectDuration" name="selectDuration"> 
      <option value="1 WEEK" >Last 1 Week</option>
      <option value="2 WEEK" >Last 2 Week </option>
      <option value="3 WEEK" >Last 3 Week</option>
    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


    <select id="selectMachine" name="selectMachine"> 
        <option value="M1" >Machine 1</option>
        <option value="M2" >Machine 2</option>
        <option value="M3" >Machine 3</option>
    </select>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


<input id="Button" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 
</div>
```

I need to take all machine names form mysql and populate the "selectMachine" drop down list box.

My php function is

```
  function selectMachine()
  {
    $strQuery = "select id, machine
           from rpt_machine
           order by machine";

    $machineResult = mysql_query($strQuery);

    while($arrayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($machineResult)) {
      $strA = $arrayRow["id"];
      $strB = $arrayRow["machine"];

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are creating functions? simply do it like this

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM ...."; //Write a query
$data = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  //Execute the query
?>
<select>
<?php
while($fetch_options = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
?>
 //Added Id for Options Element 
<option id ="<?php echo $fetch_options['id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $fetch_options['name']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options['name']; ?></option><!--Echo out options-->

<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Mr.Alien, your code solves my problem of populating the options with dynamic values from MsqDb. I have added Id for Options Element which is UUID of MySql, To Retrieve Values Based on That UUID. How to access that dynamic id in javascript. I can't use getElementById, since i requires the Id to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function similar to this one:

```
function display_dropdown($id){
  //We need to get the dropdown option from the database
  $sql = 'SELECT machine_name FROM your_table';
  $result =   mysql_query($sql) or die ('Query in display_dropdown failed:'. mysql_error());
  echo '<select name="'.$id.'" id="'.$id.'">';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo '<option value="'.$row{machine_name}.'">
            '.$row{machine_name}.'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
  echo '</td>';
}
```

To learn how to make and call php functions [go here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)